Minimizing required hypotheses to have some independence property in a classification context.
I'm trying to find a minimal set of "natural" properties that can imply higher level independence properties in classification problems.
Let say I've got samples whose classes/labels are $y_i$. I'm trying to classify them from observables/measures $x_i$.
A common independence properties that can be encountered is $\left(P\right)$: $p\left(y_1,...,y_N|x_1,...,x_N\right)=\prod_{i}p\left(y_i|x_i\right)$.
But, IMHO, it's quite a strong asumption so I wanted to find more basic hypothesis that can lead to that property.
Independency properties in a classification context. was a first, partial, attempt toward this goal which brings me to a different set of
hypotheses:

the samples' labels are mutually independent: $p\left(y_1,...,y_N\right)=\prod_{i}p\left(y_i\right)$
labels are identically distributed: $p\left(y_i\right)=p\left(y\right)=f\left(y\right)$
the measures are mutually independent: $p\left(x_1,...,x_N\right)=\prod_{i}p\left(x_i\right)$
measures are identically distributed: $p\left(x_i\right)=p\left(x\right)=g\left(x\right)$
the measure distribution for a sample, conditionally given all the labels, depends only on the given sample's label: $p\left(x_i|y_1,...,y_N\right)=p\left(x_i|y_i\right)$
measures are identically (conditionally given the sample's label) distributed: $p\left(x_i|y_i\right)=p\left(x|y\right)=h\left(x,y\right)$
measures are mutually independent conditionally given the labels: $p\left(x_1,...,x_N|y_1,...,y_N\right)=\prod_{i}p\left(x_i|y_1,...,y_N\right)$

From these hypotheses, it's quite straightforward to prove the desired high level independence property $\left(P\right)$
Is it possible to reduce this set of hypotheses (for instance are some of them redundant, useless or can completely different hypothesis can be used)?

Looking at my notes, 2, 4 and 6 may be useless.
